# Maximum number of adjacent cells

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-optimization

I'm tryng to solve the following question:

Making a connected graph in a grid of size n*n, where each cell is a node and every node can only connect to a adjacent node, What is the max number of unfilled cells adjacent to a filled cell you can get $\forall n \in N$?

By example this two grids are valid:

[image]  [image]

And this is an invalid grid because (3, 4) and (4, 3) are disconnected (Disconnected graph).

[image]

By example, in a grid of size 4, the max number is 20 and this is one graph that gets it.

[image: 4*4]

Note that *unfilled cells adjacent to a filled cell* may be off the grid. The grid only limits the filled cells.

Comment: I am very confused by the phrase "you can only fill those cells adjacent to other filled cells", can you clarify what this means? Perhaps you could explain how it applies to your $n=4$ example?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes; All the cells you fill must be connected to each other, creating a "path", you can only draw one "line" on the grid.

Comment: Does this problem come from somewhere else? But regardless, +1 for an interesting question!

Comment: Would filled cells making the shape of the letter E be valid? They are all connected to each other, but not along a single path.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I didn't consider this when i made the post, but now I gave it some thought and I think it might work too. Let me edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

In both the path and merely connected versions of the problem, for $n \in \{1,\dots,10\}$, integer linear programming yields optimal values $4, 8, 13, 20, 28, 37, 49, 60, 73, 90$, respectively.  For example, here is an optimal solution for $n=10$:
[image]

For the path version, optimal for $n=16$ is $206$, rather than your conjectured value of $208$:
[image]

Still working on the connected version for $n=16$, but we know that $206$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Pratt, your contributions have been very helpful to me. However, I am looking for results, more specifically, on grids of size $2^n\ \forall n\in Z$.
I have the conjecture that $\forall n\ \textrm{even}$ the number of UCAFC will be $(2^{n+1}+2)(1+\frac{2^n-1}{3}) + \frac{2^n-4}{3}$

Comment: Your formula correctly yields $20$ for $2^2$ but fails for $2^4$.

Comment: For the path version; have you seen a pattern that give you the optimal UCAF value $\forall n \in N$ (Or $2^{n}\ \forall n \in N$ sizes)? Maybe this spiral-like path? That could be useful information.

Answer (score 2):

In an $n \times n$ grid, we can prove an upper bound of $\frac23(n^2+4n+1)$ by constructing the graph whose vertices are the filled cells and the "shaded" cells adjacent to them. In this graph, add an edge from each shaded cell to *just one* neighboring filled cell, and add edges between adjacent filled cells to connect them.

This graph is connected, so if it has $N$ vertices, it must have at least $N-1$ edges. Let $k$ be the number of leaves (all shaded cells are leaves). All non-leaf cells have degree at most $4$, so the degree sum is at most $k + 4(N-k)$; this must be at least $2(N-1)$. From $k + 4(N-k) \ge 2(N-1)$ we get $k \le \frac23(N+1)$.

The number of leaves is at most $k$, and $N$ is at most $n^2+4n$: the $n^2$ cells of the grid, and the $4n$ cells adjacent to them. This gives us the upper bound of $\frac23(n^2+4n+1)$ that we wanted.

When $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, we can get a lower bound of $\frac23 (n^2 + 3n + 2)$ by generalizing the construction below:

```
XXXXXXXXXX
         X
         X
XXXXXXXXXX
X         
X         
XXXXXXXXXX
         X
         X
XXXXXXXXXX
```

The lower and upper bounds in this case differ by $\frac23(n-1)$.

Comment: As I interpreted the OP, the graph induced by the filled cells must have a Hamiltonian path, so your construction would not satisfy the rules. But I am not sure.

Comment: I was thinking it just needed to be connected. But to be safe, I changed the construction slightly; now it is a path. (We lose some shaded cells outside the $n\times n$ grid that way, but we gain cells that were previously filled and are now shaded inside the grid.)

Comment: Mr. Lavrov, thanks for your detailed explanation. I edited the question and now the "E" shapes are feasible, It would be nice if you would check my conjecture in Mr. Pratt's answer; i think this pattern is the optimal on grids of size $2^n\ \forall n ∈ Z \ \textrm{even}$, but i find no way to prove it: https://i.imgur.com/XcjJcOH.png

Comment: We would have to sharpen the bound of $\frac23(n^2+4n+1)$. If we get to the point where each of the $n^2+4n$ reachable cells is filled or shaded, which is without loss of generality, then we lose ground on "inefficiently shaded cells": unfilled cells adjacent to multiple filled cells. We'd have to argue that this pattern minimizes the number of inefficiently shaded cells, which seems possible but hard.